# how remove db postfix during trino schema create?

Tags: trino, apache-iceberg

I have added an iceberg connector to Trino. Then I am trying to create schema in iceberg database:

```
create schema datalake.myschema;
```

So I got he following on s3:

```
s3://mybucket/myschema.db
```

Is there a way to remove `.db` postfix?